# dataTable header with rowspan resizes and mess UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I had been developing a screen which has lots of data as . It is scrolling with dataTable.(Horizontal Scroll). There is a drpdown which should filter  values and should show only eligible TDs in scroll part. Below are Screenshots. I am hiding and showing data based on selection of a dropdown. 
Have added a class to all tds and rowspan th so that they can be toggled based on selction of dropdown.
It Shows perfect while fetching all the records. But when I hide columns , columns work perfect but header resizes its headings. 
[image]

Here is what happens on hiding th and td .td remains same , th resizes 
[image]

I tried a lot but cud not fix it. Can someone plz help

Comment: Can someone help plz.

Answer (score 0):

So I got the solution . 
U need to get your table object again and redraw it. After reading so many places about this error it seemed dataTable is still to find a fix for hiding columns in scroll part with rowspan added to it. 
What I did was adding a class to all th, td of table which needs to be hidden based on any condition , here based on selection. When I was selecting a partical type I added another class to hide the required th and tds. But Th reset sizes ,might be because of scrolls added.
It resets width of entire header leaving your td as it was . So it looks ugly.

```
 oTable.fnDraw();
```

Just take reference of your table and draw again.